How to update the OAuth 2.0 scope permissions in linkedin developer portal from w_member_social to rw_organization_social
I want to change the scope and not getting any info. How to update it from w_member_social to rw_organization_social? I have tried talking to linkedin support they told me to check in stack overflow; still I couldnt get any.
I am expecting a step by step process on how to update
